# Distinguish normal exit VS signal kill in bourne shell?

Tags: signals, sh, exit-code

In bourne shell, $? is set to the exit value of last command, but if last command is killed by a signal, $? will be set to "signal value + 128". E.g. if a command exit with value 153, $? will be set to 153, but if a command is killed by signal 25, $? will be set to "128 + 25 = 153". So after a command finish, $? = 153 could mean the command either exit normally with code 153, or be killed by signal 25. So is there any way to distinguish these two cases? That is, with $? = 153, is there any method could tell if the last command exit or is signal killed?

Thanks.

Comment: notice the low count of followers for each of your tags. Better to add an OS tag or programming language tag (only 1 of each!). I think you'll find that it is a convention (maybe it is part of POSIX definition too), that a program exit only with a value less that 128(6?). As a program can only exit with a value no higher tnan 255,   By convention, if the return is greater than 128, you know it was done via a signal.

Comment: You also need to explain in your question why this is important to you, as it is, it seems like a theoretical question, and not related to a real-life problem you're encountering. Good luck.

Comment: The POSIX spec only says that the exit status of a command terminated as the result of a signal shall be reported as greater than 128. It is silent (I think) as to whether that exit status represents signal `status` - 128. 126 and 127, though, *are* used (if not necessarily reserved) to indicate non executable or missing commands, respectively. A program should think twice about using an exit status greater than 125.